# PC stereo out to mixer

Tags: mixer, pc, stereo

I have a Behringer X2222USB mixer.

I am trying to go from the PC 1/8" stereo out to the mixer 1/4" line in and achieve stereo sound.

[image]

I'm using a 3.5mm 1/8" TRS to Dual 6.35mm 1/4" TS Mono Y-Cable

[image]

I am monitoring with headphones plugged into the phones jack of the mixer. I route the signal to the aux 1 bus.

When I do a left channel sound test, I hear sounds from both speakers. The same thing applies to the right sound test. I can unplug the left line in and not hear anything at all when playing a left channel sound test. This also applies to the right line in.

I did the same thing using the RCA inputs on this mixer using a 1/8" to RCA splitter. This does not have an aux 1 bus but instead uses a button to route sounds to the phones/control output. It works as intended wen playing a left or right channel. I get only left or right speakers playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aux 1 (send) is a mono bus.  Aux 1 (return) is stereo, but that's not what you are using here (I guess since your description is less than clear).

You can send 13/14 to the SUB 1/2 channels instead of the main mixer.  However, you will have to assign SUB 1/2 to left/right appropriately to get stereo output.

Of course this has nothing to do with the Music StackExchange and belongs on Sound instead.

Comment: I had just read this in the manual finally before returning here. You answering this helped me confirm what I read. Also, sorry about the wrong forum. Can someone move this to that channel?

Answer (score 0):

Behringer X2222USB, can be used as an USB sound card (hence the name), why not connecting it to the PC in USB and getting the sound send to that USB sound card? That would be cleaner.

If you want to stick to your solution, and the BAL setting is not working the way you expect it to, would be to plug your Jacks in two different lines and panning one of them full left and the other full right.

Not a definitive answer but I hope it helps!

Comment: @Tom Sorry about the confusion. I didn't clarify my whole setup because I was just looking for the information about the aux channels. I have 2 PCs and the 2nd PC will be using the USB with the main mix. I was needing a way to monitor only the 1st PC. Thanks for the reply.